# Unable To Load Data File With ArrayList <Java>

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I am currently working on a programming assignment for school. I've been working on my code for hours, along with searching online for an answer and had no luck.

Basically, I am given eight text files that contain several lines of data like this:

```
Henrietta   Andersen    8   10  9   10  10  9   7   9   6   10  65  80  89  24  73  95  59  78  115
```

(the order is firstname, lastname, ten homework grades, five program grades, two test grades, and one final grade)

I have no experience with an ArrayList, and I've been looking at similar projects online but cannot get any of the data to print to the output file. I am trying to print of the students' first names in the output file to check if it's working, but the only thing that gets printed is my header "FirstName." I can't get any of the data to print from my loadArray.

Here's what I've worked out in my Main so far:

```
package program1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Main {

    private static ArrayList<Student> stud = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintStream oFile = null;

        try {
            oFile = new PrintStream(new File("output.csv"));
            oFile.println("FirstName");
            for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++)
            {
                 oFile.println(stud.get(i).getStudFirstName());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void loadArray() {

        Scanner fileIn = null;

        try {
            fileIn = new Scanner(new File("CS140-001.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error opening file");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int totalHomeworks = 9;
        int totalPrograms = 5;
        int totalTests = 1;

        int[] hmwGrade = new int[totalHomeworks];
        int[] programGrade = new int[totalPrograms];
        int[] testGrade = new int[totalTests];

        while (fileIn.hasNext()) {

            Student student;

            String fName = fileIn.next();
            String lName = fileIn.next();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalHomeworks; ++i) {
                hmwGrade[i] = fileIn.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < totalPrograms; ++i) {
                programGrade[i] = fileIn.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < totalTests; ++i) {
                testGrade[i] = fileIn.nextInt();
            }

            int finalGrade = fileIn.nextInt();

            student = new Student(fName, lName, new Grades(hmwGrade, programGrade, testGrade, finalGrade));
            stud.add(student);
        }

    fileIn.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to call loadArray method from main method then only array will be populated

Comment: Yeah you never touched the method loadArray() from your main ever so you never populated the arraylist with the data you need. You should be using the loadArray() method somewhere before the for loop to print out the names.

Comment: Try closing the stream `oFile` when you are done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arraylist `stud` is not loaded with data before you started printing it to the output file.

Call `loadArray()` before you start printing to the output file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PrintStream oFile = null;
    try {
        oFile = new PrintStream(new File("output.csv"));
        oFile.println("FirstName");

        // Load the array here with student's data
        loadArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++)
        {
             oFile.println(stud.get(i).getStudFirstName());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. If I insert `loadArray();` where you inserted it, then should everything I have below that start printing to the output file or is this more still needed to do? I tried inserting it where you did but still nothing has changed.

Comment: You can try debugging your program to see if the data from source file is getting loaded into the list.